# REGEX: Select KeyWord1 if KeyWord2 is in the same string

Tags: regex, positive-lookahead

I am trying to capture **KEYWORD1** in **.NET regex engine** based on whether KeyWord2 is present in the string. So far the positive look-around solution I am using:

```
(?=.*KeyWord2)**KEYWORD1** (\m\i)
```

[RegEx Test Link](https://rubular.com/r/frgUbhzQ1oRB40)

only captures **KEYWORD1** if KeyWord2 is positioned anywhere behind **KEYWORD1** in the string. How can I optimize this in regex so that it captures all instances of **KEYWORD1** in the string despite the position of KeyWord2 being ahead, behind or both?

I'd really appreciate some insight.

Thank You

Comment: Dear Mandy8055 thank you for interest. If you click in the RegEx Test Link provided via rubular.com, you will notice the failed cases. Thank you

Comment: Dear Mandy8055 thank you for your contribution. Unfortunately the .NET RegEx proposed by you, would also select KEYWORD1 in a string without KeyWord2. The idea is to select all instances of KEYWORD1 only when the string has KeyWord2 present at any position before or behind KEYWORD1. Thank you

Comment: Dear Mandy8055 thank you so much for your contribution. Your solution solved the puzzle and it works flawlessly in the .NET regex engine.

Comment: You can use: (?=.*KeyWord2).*(KEYWORD1) then 'KEYWORD1' will always be in group1.

Comment: @Mandy8055, yes, you're right about my answer being misposted on the wrong  question. I deleted it. I was surprised that someone  gave it a downvote (update: 2 downvotes) when it obviously wasn't intended for this question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I feel bad why people downvote so early for any mistakes. This should be avoided somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regex below for your requirement:

```
\bKEYWORD1\b(?:(?<=\bKeyWord2\b.*?)|(?=.*?\bKeyWord2\b))
```

**Explanation of the above Regular Expression:**

> **gi** - Use the flags(in order to avoid any case difference) representing: **g** - global; **i** - case-insensitive
>
> **\b** - Represents a word boundary.
>
> **(?:)** - Represents a non-capturing group.
>
> **(?=.*?KeyWord2)** - Represents the **positive lookahead** which matches all **KEYWORD1** which are before **KeyWord2** read from left to right.
>
> **|** - Represents **alternation**; that is it alternates between **1st** and **2nd** alternating group.(Although, you can wrap them in group.)
>
> **(?<=KeyWord2.*?)** - Represents **infinite**(because non-fixed width lazy identifier `.*?` used) **positive lookbehind** which matches all **KEYWORD1** which are behind of **KeyWord2**.

You can find the above regex demo [**here.**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbKEYWORD1%5cb%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3c%3d%5cbKeyWord2%5cb.*%3f%29%7c%28%3f%3d.*%3f%5cbKeyWord2%5cb%29%29&i=KEYWORD1+is+ahead+of+KeyWord2%0d%0aKEYWORD1+is+ahead+of+Keyword2+and+another+KeyWord2%0d%0aKeyWord2+is+behind+KEYWORD1%0d%0aKEYWORD1+is+ahead+of+KEYWORD1+and+behind+KeyWord2%0d%0aKeyWord2+is+twice+of+KeyWord2+and+in+the+end+KEYWORD1%0d%0aKEYWORD1+is+KeyWord2&o=m)

**NOTE** - For the record, these engines support **infinite lookbehind**:

- .NET (C#, VB.NET etc.)
- [**Matthew Barnett's**](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) regex module for Python
- [**JGSoft**](https://www.just-great-software.com/) (EditPad etc.; not available in a programming language).
- [**ECMASCRIPT(Javascript)**](https://regex101.com/r/WlOVXX/4)

As far as I know, they are the only ones.

Comment: Also it could be shortened to `KEYWORD1(?:(?<=Keyword2.*?)|(?=.*?Keyword2))`. Maybe a better choice.

Comment: @CarySwoveland it matches; Please add `-i` flag and check once. [**Here**](https://regex101.com/r/OHSN3T/4) is the sample run. Please let me know if some other problem persists

Comment: Excellent answer! Very instructive. (Yes, I forgot the case indifferent flag, or put another way, I had written `"Keyword2"` rather than `"KeyWord2"`.)

Comment: A small point: you really don't need "Edit:" in answers. If you circulated a draft of a paper, obtained useful suggestions and incorporated some in a revision, you wouldn't include "Edit:" because you would be trying to write a text that would be most useful to readers, rather than telling a story of how you got to your answer. I think the same applies to SO answers. Put another way, why emphasize an edit? I personally use comments for thank you's and credits, and sometimes for reporting what I had written previously. Again, that's to keep the answer focused on just answering the question.

Comment: I edited my answer @CarySwoveland. I added the **word breaks** too. Initially I used to think that all the people who help in a great wiki answer should be given the credit. That is the only reason I mentioned the same.

Comment: I agree, but just think a comment is the best place to do that. Others disagree, however.

Comment: @revo, nice one!

Answer (score 0):

If one uses a regex engine that supports `\G` and `\K`, the following regular expression could be used.

```
^(?=.*\bKeyWord2\b)|\G.*?\K\bKEYWORD1\b
```

with the case-indifferent flag and, depending on requirements, multiline flag, set.

[PCRE demo](https://regex101.com/r/vkCqaL/1/)

With PCRE (PHP) and some other regex engines the anchor `\G` matches the end of previous match. For the first match attempt, \G is equivalent to `\A`, matching the start of the string. See [this discussion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) for details.

`\K` resets the starting point of the reported match to the current position of the engine's internal string pointer. Any previously consumed characters are not included in the final match. In effect, `\K` causes the engine to "forget" everything matched up to that point. Details can be found [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html).

As shown at the link, there are four matches of the string

```
The KEYWORD1 before KeyWord2 then KEYWORD1 and KEYWORD1 again
```

They are an empty string at the beginning of the string and each of the three instances of `KEYWORD1`. In fact for every string matched one of the matches will be an empty string at the beginning of the string. Empty strings must therefore be disregarded when making substitutions.