# regex for splitting a string while ignoring the brackets

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to split a string with **space-character** but ignoring the space between two brackets.
The code i used is:

```
String s = "hello (split this) string";
String reg = "(?<=([^\\(].*))( )(?=(.*[^\\)]))";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(reg));
```

My expected output is:

```
[hello , (split this) , string]
```

but i get this error

> *Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 12
>   (?<=([^(].*))z(?=(.*[^)]))  *

I need a regex to get the expected output.
So, somebody please help.

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/TzhQ2h/1) help?[Code](https://onlinegdb.com/Skjoo-xh8)

Comment: I run your code and I don't get an error.

Comment: Error will occur in java because op is using variable length quantifier in lookbehinds. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616478/positive-lookbehind-regex-obvious-maximum-length) Although there are [some engines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61831998/7571182) which allow variable length qunatifiers inside lookbehinds.

Comment: is possseble nesters `((()))` ?

Comment: Replace the comma with `\s+` in the linked solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why would you mark this a duplicate when the answer there does not check if a certain character is BETWEEN a pair of other characters ? Essentially you're saying when a question is posed twice all others should be closed and linked to that one even though it doesn't answer it correctly and is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below regex to achieve your requirement:

```
[ ](?=[^\)]*?(?:\(|$))
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`[ ]`** - Represents a space character.
>
> **`(?=[^\)]*?(?:\(|$))`** - Represents a positive look-ahead asserting everything inside of `()`.
>
> **`(?:)`** - Represents a [**non-capturing group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).
>
> **`|`** - Represents alternation.
>
> **`$`** - Represents the end of the test String.

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/TzhQ2h/3)

[image: Pictorial representation]

**IMPLEMENTATION IN JAVA**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "hello (split this) string";
        String reg = "[ ](?=[^\\)]*?(?:\\(|$))";
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(reg)));
    }
}

// output: [hello, (split this), string]
```

You can find the above implementation [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/ByJvQ7e3U)

Comment: thanks man, it worked. But, i don't know what is the meaning of regex. You gave an explanation but i don't understand what is meant by this `(?:)` symbol.

Comment: I updated the answer @Logesh-0304. You can also read the meaning of above regex in the demo which I provided. On right hand side of [regex101](https://regex101.com/) you can see the explanation tab; there also you can notice the same.

Comment: Thankyou , now i understand some about regex

Answer (score 1):

Try `"(?:[^ (]+|(?>\\([^()]*\\))|\\()+(?=[ ]|$)"`

notes

- use to match all elements instead of split
- will match unbalanced parens and use a atomic group on paren like `( kk hh )`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/bAHDfH/1)